# SQL converting Date datatype from Varchar to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

so I'm trying to convert my date column datatype from `varchar` to `date`.

Currently my date is in `d/m/yyyy` format and I want to convert to standard `mm/dd/yyyy`

Here's the script that I'm running

```
update [table]
set [PERIOD]= CONVERT(varchar(20),cast([PERIOD] as date),101)
```

But I'm getting an error

`Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Any tips or am I stuck?

Comment: Are all of the dates in a recognizable format(by SQL) in the table?

Comment: going back to the ol pre Y2K format eh?

Comment: `mm/dd/yy` is hardly *standard*, at least since people learned a few decades ago the problems with storing 2-digit years. (Unless, of course, you've discovered the secret of time-travel and are posting here from the 1990s before SO existed.)

Comment: @KenWhite Oops I screwed up. `mm/dd/yyyy` is what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks Ken

Comment: sorry @Kritner I meant `mm/dd/yyyy`. Thanks for catching that

Comment: Check whether there is junk data in [PERIOD] column. What is the datatype of [PERIOD] column? @Mike V.

Comment: @SarathAvanavu datatype is `varchar(MAX)`

Comment: @MikeV.  You are definitely getting the error because you cannot `CAST()` `d/m/yyyy` as `DATE`, hence the `CONVERT()` in my answer.  If you get the same error using `CONVERT()` instead of `CAST()` then it means you have invalid values.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest instead of updating one string date to another format of string date, that you add a new `DATE` or `DATETIME` field to store the dates properly.

```
ALTER [table] ADD Proper_Date DATE
GO
UPDATE [table]
SET Proper_Date = convert(date, [PERIOD], 103)
```

If you must, you can wrap the above in another `CONVERT()`:

```
update [table]
set [PERIOD]= CONVERT(varchar(20),convert(date,[PERIOD], 103),101)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you can segregate the day and month and the year by using substring or any other string functions then use the below query

```
update tableA
set period = convert(datetime,cast(day(1)as varchar)+'/'+cast(MONTH(1)as varchar)+'/2014',102)
```

Hope its works.

Answer (score 0):

You may have junk value and can get the junk values by executing the following query

```
SELECT [PERIOD] 
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE ISDATE([PERIOD]) = 0
```

To avoid junk values and update the rest try the below

```
update YOURTABLE
set [PERIOD]= CONVERT(varchar(20),cast([PERIOD] as date),101)
WHERE ISDATE([PERIOD]) = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
update [table]
set [PERIOD]= CONVERT(varchar(20),CONVERT(date,[PERIOD] ,103),101)
```

Problem in your query is

```
cast([PERIOD] as date)
```

You cannot directly convert `d/m/yyyy` format to `date`. So use `103` style to convert

Comment: Whoever downvoted please comment whats wrong in the answer so that i can improve.